# Chain path commands in raphael.js

Tags: javascript, path, svg, raphael

I would like to know, is there a way to build on the same path raphael.js?

I mean, i wont for example build a path using a for() cycle. I thought the the variable returned path = paper.path(...) could be used to increase the path using c.path(). But this throw an error since the method path() doesn't exist...

The only solution i found now is to build a string and then pass it in one time to paper.path()

Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the attribute 'path' to update a path.
`initialPath="M......."`;

```
path=paper.path(initialPath);

initialPath=initialPath+" 50 200";
path.attr({path:initialPath});
```

Comment: I saw that in the older version of raphael there were functions like linrTo() to build paths and they were pretty handy when using variables! now i'm building them using string and spaces ' m'+ var+' '+var etc... there isn't a more prettier way?